# Function to return a spannable and append it to a string in textview

Tags: android, text, styles, textview, spannable

I am trying to create a function that will take a string "word" as an argument, apply span styling to the string and return it as a spannable string that I can `""+insert+""` into a string in a `TextView`. Thank you in advance for any help you can offer with this.

Here is the function I have so far.

```
public Spannable fr(String word){
  Spannable WordtoSpan = new SpannableString(word);        
  WordtoSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), 0, 
      word.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
  WordtoSpan.setSpan(new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD), 0, 
      word.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
  return WordtoSpan;
}
```

and the code that should display the spannable inline with my text.

```
TextView tview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.accents_view);
tview.setText(Html.fromHtml("<strong>Text String</strong> "+fr("style_this"));
```

The application will either load the text without styling or the app will crash. Not sure what I'm doing wrong but I'm guessing it has something to do with mixing fromHtml text with spannables. Any work arounds?

If I remove the `Html.fromHtml()` and wrap the entire text with my `fr()` function it works. I get bold blue text. But I need to be able to make only certain words styled... It would also be nice to be able to reference vars from my string.xml file instead of hard coding them in, for multilingual support.

Comment: If I remove the Html.fromHtml() and wrap the entire text with my fr() function it works. I get bold blue text. But I need to be able to make only certain words styled... It would also be nice to be able to reference vars from my string.xml file instead of hard coding them in, for multilingual support.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may find this helpful,

```
TextView tview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.accents_view);
tview.setText(Html.fromHtml("<font color='blue'>Text</font> " 
    + "<font color='red'>String</font>"));
```

Comment: This works fine however I understand that the html or css styles applicable to strings in android textviews are somewhat limited e.g; http://commonsware.com/blog/Android/2010/05/26/html-tags-supported-by-textview.html. I want to be able to add things like background color, and padding to certain parts of the text. Is this possible with static html tags?

Comment: You'll have to try it... I'm not certain on all of that myself, but foreground-color and font-weight are easy (and `&nbsp;` will work too).

Comment: Thanks Elliott. I'll have to practice more with Spannables to create more flexible styled text, but for now this will do. For now I'm settling for a function that returns the string with html styles so I don't have to type them each time I want to highlight a word!